# getting the SQL Server Schema for a table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, schema

I have the following C# code that I am trying to get to return the stored procedure results along with the schema of those results. Below is how my code (simplified) currently looks...

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("MyStoredProcedure");
IDataReader drData = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);

DataTable tblSchema;
tblSchema  = drData.GetSchemaTable();
```

The GetSchemaTable is returning empty. I have read that I need to pass CommandBehavior.KeyInfo to the ExecuteReader method but I am unclear how this would look in the way I have the code structured since I am passing the dbCommand to the ExecuteReader.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using System.Data.Common.DbCommand, then, i think you can call

```
IDataReader drData = dbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
```

**[EDIT]**

You can also use

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
db.LoadDataSet(dbCommand, ds, "tableName");
```

or

```
db.ExecuteDataSet
```

This is a [link](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/08/2686.aspx) a found useful

Hope it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get a schema for a SQL Server stored procedure is to use the sql:

```
EXEC sp_help MyStoredProcedure
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933429(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassing old code time. This is what I used when I was first learning .NET 1.1, and the guy who taught me insisted on using DataSets/Tables instead of business objects. It's about 5 years old and ripped out of an old library, but given a table name, it'll give you a dataset containing the table schema.

```
public static DataSet GetTableSchema(string tableName)
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM {0}", tableName);

    using (SqlConnection localSqlConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, localSqlConn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

        sda.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, tableName);
        sda.Fill(ds, tableName);

        sda.Dispose();

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better answer would be as follows:
[2013 Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107)
The article show multiple ways to retrieve table information, here is one method.

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
DataTable schemaTable; 
SqlDataReader myReader; 

//Open a connection to the SQL Server Northwind database.
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=server;User ID=login;
                       Password=password;Initial Catalog=Northwind";
cn.Open();

//Retrieve records from the Employees table into a DataReader.
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

//Retrieve column schema into a DataTable.
schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();

//For each field in the table...
foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows){
    //For each property of the field...
    foreach (DataColumn myProperty in schemaTable.Columns) {
    //Display the field name and value.
    Console.WriteLine(myProperty.ColumnName + " = " + myField[myProperty].ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Pause.
    Console.ReadLine();
}

//Always close the DataReader and connection.
myReader.Close();
cn.Close();
```